# pnp listview : column sorting expands all groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp

I've asked about this issue on Microsoft 365 & Power Platform Community github but haven't had a response.

I'm using the [PnP SPFx Listview control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ListView/) displaying a list with groups. The issue is when I click on a column header to sort, **all** the groups expand and you are taken back to the top of the list. So then the user needs to scroll back to the group they had opened originally, a poor user experience.

It's probably an issue that should be fixed within the plugin, but I'm trying to come up with a work around and haven't been successful so far.